# Binary incompatibility in plugins detected in Play 2.1.3 project after upgrading to IDEA 13.1?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.1

After updating IntelliJ IDEA to **13.1** last night I can't use Run/Debug config anymore. It happens in a project I've been working on in IDEA **13.0.x** for the past couple of months -- now it shows me the message and I have no idea how I can solve this.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /www/play20apps/cnproject/project
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
[error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies:
[error]     asm:asm
[error]     asm:asm-tree
[error]     asm:asm-util
[error]     org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent
[error]     jline:jline
[error]     junit:junit
[error]     com.jcraft:jsch
[error]     commons-logging:commons-logging
[error]     commons-codec:commons-codec
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[error] Not a valid command: run
[error] run
[error]    ^

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I didn't change Play version since yesterday of course and running application with common command line works as expected.

Also tried to create new run config after plugins' update with no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you include `*.sbt` and `*.scala* build files? Can you also include `last` for the full log as instructed by sbt? You may want to run `project plugins` and poke around when you're inside `plugins` project. What does `update` say there?

Comment: Not now, I had to downgrade, as need to work atm, will do it in next 2 days earliest. sbt version is `0.12.2` and Play is `2.1.3`, dzięki :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `-Djline.terminal=` to `JVM Options` [should fix it](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5283/8pdd.png).

`last` log [reports this](http://pastebin.com/XMUY3EPG).

The relevant part:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: none
    at jline.Terminal.setupTerminal(Terminal.java:65)
    at jline.Terminal.getTerminal(Terminal.java:26)
    at sbt.JLine$.sbt$JLine$$terminal(LineReader.scala:65)
```

where `none` is probably passed via `-Djline.terminal=none`.

Comment: I'm guessing that `-Djline.terminal=` just clears the `none` so it's equivalent to `null`? If so, why does `none` _not_ work?